# ModelState.IsValid only when defining object in action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm just starting off with MVC, so perhaps this is a silly question.

Going over Data Annotations to perform validations, I've noticed that `ModelState.IsValid` only works when the object is defined in the Action as below, also property names have to match input names:

**CustomerController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Submit(Customer obj) <-- here
{
    //Customer obj = new Customer();
    //obj.CustomerName = Request.Form["CustomerName"];
    //obj.CustomerCode = Request.Form["CustomerCode"];

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return View("Customer", obj);
    }
    else
    {
         return View("EnterCustomer");
    }            
}
```

**Customer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyFirstWebApp.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{3,3}[0-9]{4,4}$")]
        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EnterCustomer.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EnterCustomer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <form action="Submit" method="post">
            Customer Name: <input name="CustomerName" type="text" /> <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CustomerName) <br />
            Customer Code: <input name="CustomerCode" type="text" /> <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CustomerCode) <br />
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I define the obj as below, ModelState.IsValid is always true when I enter invalid values to perform validations, can someone tell me why?

**CustomerController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Submit()
{
    Customer obj = new Customer();
    obj.CustomerName = Request.Form["CustomerName"];
    obj.CustomerCode = Request.Form["CustomerCode"];

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return View("Customer", obj);
    }
    else
    {
         return View("EnterCustomer");
    }            
}
```

Comment: use `TryValidateModel(obj)`

Comment: @JamieD77 TryValidateModel(obj) worked, please make it an answer so I can give you the credit, also, just noticed that TryValidateModel can be used either way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use TryValidateModel inside a Controller to validate a model.

```
Customer obj = new Customer();
obj.CustomerName = Request.Form["CustomerName"];
obj.CustomerCode = Request.Form["CustomerCode"];

if (TryValidateModel(obj))
{
     return View("Customer", obj);
}
else
{
     return View("EnterCustomer");
}
```